# Java 1.6 and detecting samba symbolic link

Tags: java, linux

I have a legacy project with java 1.6 and I have a path on Linux to SMB(samba) file like this :

`smb://server14/sambashare/folder1/somedir/myfile` , how can I found out if
`myfile` is symbolic link or not?

Comment: Is it written somewhere that it does not support symlinks?

Comment: Given how ancient Java 1.6 is, your best bet might be to invoke an external binary that gives you this information.  `smbclient` should be able to help when invoked with the `stat` command.